# PHP code is not inserting data to authors, molecules and instrument on MYSQL database after adding some fields

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","registration");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$authors = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['authors']);
$project = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['project']);
$molecules = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['molecules']);
$instrument = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['instrument']);
$abstract = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['abstract']);
$keywords = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['keywords']);

$sql="INSERT INTO `chemia`(`authors`, `project`, `molecules`,     `instrument`, `abstract`, `keywords`) VALUES('$authors', '$project',   '$molecules','$instrument', '$abstract', '$keywords')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

header("Location:viewsubmitted.php"); 
exit;

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This code is not inserting some columns in my database i.e. authors, instrument and molecules yet it insert the others perfectly

Comment: did you get any error?did you checked that all values are coming perfectly? Because i din't see any checks regarding that in your code. Also use `prepared statements` to prevent your code from SQL INJECTION.

Comment: The fact that it works sometimes indicates there is a problem with the actual  data. Can you post a sample of what is and what isn't successful?

Comment: Dear Jeff, It inserts id, abstract, keywords, project yet when i try to insert molecules and instrument, it give blanks in the database without error. These field are required.